# How to get process (external program) time, cpu usage for process run from java application?

Tags: java, external-process

I know how to run an external program in java:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
       "\"c:/my-simple-app.exe\"");
    p.waitFor();
  }
}
```

But how can I get all of the program properties when I run it like this? I mean: system time for this process (how much system time it took to run), cpu usage (only for this exact process), ... Is it possible?

Comment: No, not through standard APIs

Comment: @MadProgrammer: so are there any other ways? (how to make it?)

Comment: As far as I can figure, you'd need some kind of native interface capable of performing the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this program in a separate thread, then run `tasklist /v` process (if Windows), intercept output, split lines into columns, find `my-simple-app.exe` and get necessary info. If tasklist info is not enough, then read process ID column form tasklist output and run some other util to get more info.

Comment: ok but lets say that my program which I ran from Java end before I can get this info, what then? I would like to make it that way: 1. run an external program in Java 2. wait for it to end 3. get the parameters I wrote about earlier - cp usage, system time for this program. If it isnt possible in Java, maybe in ay other language ... ?

Comment: I think it's only possible if my-simple-app.exe will be getting this info about itself while running and writing it to stdout which you can intercept and read